# How do I wrap using flexbox and media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with four boxes. The container all together should be the width of the window.

Above 720px, there should be one row of four boxes.
Below 720px, there should be two rows of two boxes.
Below 600px, there should be four rows of one box.

I'm confused what I should put in the media queries.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .container {
    ?
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    ?
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the flex items to wrap at your breakpoints.

Here's a [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L04gvt8m/).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 34%;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 51%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Note that with `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be exact (25%, 50%, 100%), which can result in unequal wrapping if you were to add margin space.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap. This will ensure plenty of space for margins, but not enough space for an extra item.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grids to achieve this. If you name them like I did in the snippet, it is easy to alter the sequence of the columns.

```css
.container {
      display: grid;
      grid-auto-rows: 200px;
      grid-auto-columns: auto;
      grid-template-areas:
      "column1 column2 column3 column4";
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .column {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .column1 {
      grid-area: column1;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .column2 {
      grid-area: column2;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .column3 {
      grid-area: column3;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .column4 {
      grid-area: column4;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    @media (max-width: 720px) {
      .container {
        grid-template-areas:
        "column1 column2"
        "column3 column4";
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .container {
        grid-template-areas:
        "column1"
        "column2"
        "column3"
        "column4";
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column column1"></div>
        <div class="column column2"></div>
        <div class="column column3"></div>
        <div class="column column4"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

More info about grids in CSS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)